# Rendered Value of Text Field does not change if attribute of the object changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using the Date Text Field of Material UI. When I pass an attribute of an object, the rendered value of the Text Field does not change even though the value of the object attribute changes.

```
 const [data, setData] = useState({
    title: new Date("2014-08-18T21:11:54"),
  });

  function changeData(key, obj) {
    var duplicateData = data;
    duplicateData[key] = obj;
    setData(duplicateData);
  }

 <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
           <KeyboardDatePicker
             disableToolbar
             id="date-picker-inline"
             label={item2}
             KeyboardButtonProps={{
                "aria-label": "change date",
                 }}
             autoOk={true}
             value={data.title}
             onChange={(date) => {
               changeData(title, date);
             }}
              />
 </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

When I pass a constant, the rendered value changes as desired. How can I make the first case work?

```
 const [dateTrial, setDateTrial] = useState(new Date("2014-08-18T21:11:54"));

 <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
           <KeyboardDatePicker
             disableToolbar
             id="date-picker-inline"
             label={item2}
             KeyboardButtonProps={{
                "aria-label": "change date",
                 }}
             autoOk={true}
             value={dateTrial}
             onChange={(date) => {
               setDateTrial(date);                    
               }}
              />
 </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are just assigning the state to a new variable here `var duplicateData = data;`. This does not create a new object . Now both `data` and `duplicate` points to the same object . so mutating `duplicateData[key] = obj;` will mutate the state as well . In react mutating the state directly will cause issues . So what you need instead is to create a new copy of the state object .

```
const duplicateData = {...data}
```

The es6 spread syntax does that for you .

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
    title: new Date("2014-08-18T21:11:54"),
  });

  function changeData(key, obj) {
    const duplicateData = {...data}; 
    duplicateData[key] = obj;
    setData(duplicateData);
  }

 <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
           <KeyboardDatePicker
             disableToolbar
             id="date-picker-inline"
             label={item2}
             KeyboardButtonProps={{
                "aria-label": "change date",
                 }}
             autoOk={true}
             value={data.title}
             onChange={(date) => {
               changeData('title', date); // change the title to string
             }}
              />
 </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems way easier:

```
onChange={(date) => {
  setData({title: date});
}}
```

as `KeyboardDatePicker` prop - no need for your own "external" function `changeData` and the connected hassle with types and instances. Makes no difference if you put "title" in quotes or not.